# Conversion of pdf/word document into clean HTML

Tags: django-templates

I wanted to convert the content of a pdf file into clean HTML which I can then use into django template.Any suggestion which tool I can use to get it converted without much HTML 
disorientation and jibberish.

Comment: try `pandoc` http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display or convert the actual contents? If you just want to display the document then I would recommend some of the open source libraries such as [PDFJS](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) or [FlexPaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com). These libraries can be used to convert the document to HTML5, HTML4 or Flash